# How do you create a mobile friendly Like Gate for a Page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-like

I've put a Like Gate on a few of my Facebook Pages and I'm getting a lot of complaints saying that people can't access the content via their mobile device since the mobile version of the facebook website, and the facebook apps for ios/android, don't support tabs on Facebook.

I see there are services out there (I'm not sure how legit they are) that offer a way to create a mobile like gate for your page tab, but I can't find any documentation on how they do it.  These services are not suitable for me, because the content on my tab is custom and dynamic.

So, how can I create a interstitial page for a mobile page that requires the visitor to have liked my Page on Facebook before they can proceed?  This has to work for new users, as well as existing users who re-visit the tab and *without* requiring an install to an application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take for a mobile site is to check that the user has liked the page in question via the JS SDK.

If you have a logged-in user to your application, you can Subscribe to the `authResponseChange` FB event within your JS SDK initialization, or call a function directly to make an API request to verify if the user is a fan of your page.

In your initialization:

```js
FB.init({appId: YOUR_FB_APP_ID_HERE });
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  // React to a user clicking an on-page Like button:
  FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", verifyUserLikesPage);     
}
```

You can verify that the user likes the appropriate page in the like handler:

```js
function verifyUserLikesPage() {
  FB.api("/me/likes/"+FBID_OF_PAGE_TO_ENSURE_THEY_LIKE, function(apiResponse){
    if (apiResponse.data && apiResponse.data.length > 0)
      // User likes the page. Enabled them to proceed
    else
      // User does not like the page. Require they click Like.
  }
}
```

More information on the edge.create subscribe via JS available here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires that the user be installed to my application; and because this is just a tab - there is no installation. (An installation dialog would be too heavy for this use case)